# how to mass convert json to csv?

Tags: json, csv, export-to-csv

Greetings is there a tool to mass convert json to csv like [this](http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm).

EDIT 1
I'm working on a DND application and i am using [this](https://github.com/adrpadua/5e-database) jsons but before putting them into a db i want to mass convert them into csv and not one by one with an online tool.

Comment: Why downvote without comment is the format of the question wrong?

Comment: It's better to share an example of input. JSON is not a flatten structured text as CSV, it could contains complex structure, table inside table, ecc.

Comment: Ive shared the json's im using

Comment: A generic tool that do what you want probably does not exist, but it's possible to build a script that do it. It's necessary to map the different structures and the desired output schema

Comment: Any pointers on that?

Comment: A great JSON tool is jq (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). With a JSON query like this `.[]|[.index,.name,.cost.quantity,.cost.unit,.damage.damage_type.name]|@csv`, you can have a CSV output (https://jqplay.org/s/4GCJSClTCK). I have extracted some fields from this https://github.com/adrpadua/5e-database/raw/master/5e-SRD-Equipment.json